# C++ deleting members of a list in a for loop

Tags: c++, for-loop

Consider you have a have class Base with two functions foo() and goo() and a bool boolean that is assigned either 0 or 1 when a Base object is created. Then we have the following:

```
//declaring a list
std::list<Base*> base;
//creating 10 objects of Base and storing on the list
for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
{
    Base *b = new Base();
    base.push_back(b);
}
for (auto i = base.begin(); i != base.end();)
{
    Base *e = *i;

    e->foo();
    e->goo();
    if (e->boolean == false)
    {
        i = base.erase(i);
        delete e;
    }
    else
        i++;
}
```

First question: Why did the programmer omit the third parameter in the for-loop? Is it i++ implicitly?
Second question: Please explain me when to use erase and/or delete or both and why it was necessary in this snippet. Also explain me the need of Base *e = *i; instead of just calling i->foo(); i->goo() directly. Thank you very much :)

Comment: Note `i = base.erase(i);`. `erase` returns the next item after the erased item. Adding an extra ++ onto this would be bad.

Comment: That answers my first question, thank you. What about the second one?

Comment: @Powereleven: Because by the time you're deleting the pointer, it no longer exists in the `list`; if you didn't save off a copy, you'd have leaked the memory with no hope of cleaning it up properly (this is why real code tends to use `std::shared_ptr` or `std::unique_ptr`, so it doesn't have to manually manage memory).

Comment: Note that with 'for' all three parts are optional. for(;;) is perfectly legal and is equivalent to for(;1;)

Comment: Manual delete would be unneeded with `std::list<std::unique_ptr<Base>> base;`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## First Question

Note `i = base.erase(i);`. After erasing, `i` is invalid, the list item it pointed to is gone, so `erase` returns the next item after the erased item to allow you to continue on through the list. Because `i` is already referencing what would have been `i++` adding an extra `i++` onto this in the `for` loop would skip an item in the list.

If no item was erased, the regular `i++` is handled in the else case.

Take a look at the [Erase-Remove idiom](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Erase%E2%80%93remove_idiom) for a nicer way to do this.

## Second Question

`i` is an iterator to a pointer to `Base` <sup>1</sup> so `i->foo()` would try to invoke `foo` on the pointer, and pointers have no `foo`. Rather than pity the `foo` you have to first dereference the iterator and then dereference the pointer.

You can't `i->->foo();`, but you could `(*i)->foo();`. `(*i)` dereferences the iterator and gives you the pointer for the `->foo()` part.

```
Base *e = *i;
```

caches the dereferenced iterator, so

```
e->foo();
```

is the same as

```
(*i)->foo();
```

Maybe it makes the code easier to read. Maybe it has a small performance benefit. Depends on how much you have to `(*i)` and how descriptive a name you give `e`. `e` sucks as a variable name because you had to ask this question. A good variable name would have told you what was going on.

<sup>1</sup> You almost never want to do this, by the way. Let library containers contain instances of objects, not pointers so they can manage all of the memory for you. Making memory management easier was a huge part of what they were designed for.

However in this case, the name `Base` suggests that polymorphism is in play. A list of polymorphic objects is about the only time you want a container of pointers. But Look into [using smart pointers](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory) to manage the life of any dynamically allocated polymorphic objects.

Comment: You guessed right :P Base had a virtual function and a few derived classes that overridden it.

Answer (score 0):

If the increment expression to 'for' is omitted there is simply no action taken.

```
for(init ; test; increment)
```

body

is *always* equivalent to:

```
{
  init ;
  while(test)
    body
}
```

The surrounding braces form the C++ standard behavior of having the initialized variables limited to the for statement